# Magento2. Change template in protected $_template

Tags: template, magento2

The question is easy.

How to change template, whose path exists only in protected property $_template

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If inside the class

```
$this->setTemplate('Vendor_Module::path/to/template.phtml');
```

if outside, then

```
$block->setTemplate('Vendor_Module::path/to/template.phtml');
```

where `$block` is the instance of your block.

Comment: Thank you for response. I need to change template for some custom block in magento in admin area (in other words outside of the block). To use 2nd variant - I need instantiate this block (by createBlock) or I can change it for its child. All variant are not suitable. In 1st magento I could rewrite block. Here this feature is impossible. Also impossible to do this with plugin.

Comment: why is it impossible to use a plugin (interceptor)? Also, you might be able to change the template via a layout file. but that depends on what you are trying to change. I think you should ask an other question explaining what exactly you want to achieve. I answered your question, and did my best with the information you provided.

Comment: Thank you for your time. Yes, probably it can be achieved via interception method getTemplate (maybe). it was impossible to change via layout because this block created in php. I changed template via observer in _prepareLayout (as you offered with $block->setTemplate)